# How to divide the selected element with the sum values in the row, except the values on the diagonal PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas

I am doing some statistics.

I have data frame:

```
tag a   b    c   d   e   f   
 a  5   2    3   2   0   1
 b  2   4    3   2   0   1
 c  3   4    3   2   0   3
 d  2   4    3   2   0   1
 e  0   4    3   2   0   8
 f  1   4    3   2   0   1
```

I want to create new dataframe:

```
tag a   b    c   d   e   f   
 a  0   x    
 b      0        
 c           0       
 d               0      
 e                   0   Y  
 f                       0
```

where x would be equal the correspodenting element on that place, divided with the sum of elements in that row, except the element on the diagonal. So the X is: `X = 2/(2+3+2+0+1)`

And for the example `Y = 8/(0+4+3+2+8)`

After that I need to add one more column which will be calculated:
 -sum[each element in the row * log (of that element)]

I am sorry for this trivial question, I used to work in R, and for this task I need to work in pandas.

Comment: Why is `e, e` `9`?

Comment: that's mistake. sry :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `np.fill_diagonal` to mask diagonal elements, then perform index aligned division using `DataFrame.div`:

```
u = df.set_index('tag')
np.fill_diagonal(u.values, 0)

v = u.div(u.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
v 

        a         b         c         d    e         f
tag                                                   
a    0.00  0.250000  0.375000  0.250000  0.0  0.125000
b    0.25  0.000000  0.375000  0.250000  0.0  0.125000
c    0.25  0.333333  0.000000  0.166667  0.0  0.250000
d    0.20  0.400000  0.300000  0.000000  0.0  0.100000
e    0.00  0.235294  0.176471  0.117647  0.0  0.470588
f    0.10  0.400000  0.300000  0.200000  0.0  0.000000
```

---

"After that I need to add one more column which will be calculated: -sum[each element in the row * log (of that element)]"

You can do this with

```
v['log_sum'] = -np.ma.masked_invalid(v * np.log(v)).sum(1)
v

        a         b         c         d    e         f   log_sum
tag                                                             
a    0.00  0.250000  0.375000  0.250000  0.0  0.125000 -8.965402
b    0.25  0.000000  0.375000  0.250000  0.0  0.125000 -8.965402
c    0.25  0.333333  0.000000  0.166667  0.0  0.250000 -8.461294
d    0.20  0.400000  0.300000  0.000000  0.0  0.100000 -9.560926
e    0.00  0.235294  0.176471  0.117647  0.0  0.470588 -9.708363
f    0.10  0.400000  0.300000  0.200000  0.0  0.000000 -9.560926
```

Comment: X = .25, Y = .47 (cross-verify with the OP)

Comment: Thank you! And how to add the new column which would be calculate by formula: -sum[each element in the row * log (of that element)] ?

Comment: Thank you. :) You made my day. <3

Answer (score 1):

`numpy.eye` + a bit of arithmetic

---

```
u = df.iloc[:, 1:].values
x, _ = df.shape
m = 1 - np.eye(x)
n = u * m
n / n.sum(1, keepdims=1)
```

```
array([[0.   , 0.25 , 0.375, 0.25 , 0.   , 0.125],
       [0.25 , 0.   , 0.375, 0.25 , 0.   , 0.125],
       [0.25 , 0.333, 0.   , 0.167, 0.   , 0.25 ],
       [0.2  , 0.4  , 0.3  , 0.   , 0.   , 0.1  ],
       [0.   , 0.235, 0.176, 0.118, 0.   , 0.471],
       [0.1  , 0.4  , 0.3  , 0.2  , 0.   , 0.   ]])
```

---

To maintain the original frame:

```
pd.DataFrame(index=df.tag, data=n / n.sum(1, keepdims=1), columns=df.columns[1:])
```

```
        a         b         c         d    e         f
tag
a    0.00  0.250000  0.375000  0.250000  0.0  0.125000
b    0.25  0.000000  0.375000  0.250000  0.0  0.125000
c    0.25  0.333333  0.000000  0.166667  0.0  0.250000
d    0.20  0.400000  0.300000  0.000000  0.0  0.100000
e    0.00  0.235294  0.176471  0.117647  0.0  0.470588
f    0.10  0.400000  0.300000  0.200000  0.0  0.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

One more possibility using [`np.identity`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.identity.html) with boolean values.

```
df = df.mul(~np.identity(len(df), dtype=np.bool))
df.div(df.sum(1), 0)

    a       b           c           d           e   f
a   0.00    0.250000    0.375000    0.250000    0.0 0.125000
b   0.25    0.000000    0.375000    0.250000    0.0 0.125000
c   0.25    0.333333    0.000000    0.166667    0.0 0.250000
d   0.20    0.400000    0.300000    0.000000    0.0 0.100000
e   0.00    0.235294    0.176471    0.117647    0.0 0.470588
f   0.10    0.400000    0.300000    0.200000    0.0 0.000000
```